# Is there any absolutely continuous function $f$ and a null set $X$ such that $f(X)$ is not a null set?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, continuity

[Here (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Properties) there are some properties of absolutely continous functions. Some of them requires a closed interval to be the domain of $f$.

So, I would like an example of an absolutly continuous function $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ and a set $X\subset (a,b)$ of zero Lebesgue measure such that $f(X)$ has not zero Lebesgue measure.

Thanks.

Comment: An absolute continuous function is uniformly continuous and hence uniquely continuously extendable to a function $F \colon [a,b]\to \mathbb R$. Now apply what you know.

Comment: @martini can we ensure that the extension of $f$ is absolutely continuous?

Comment: Ignore my earlier comment, I wasn't paying attention.

Comment: What do you mean by AC on $(a,b)$? Do you mean AC on any closed sub-interval, or do you mean the usual definition with the exception that the sub intervals are chosen from $(a,b)$ instead? The function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is AC on any closed sub interval of $(0,1)$, but is not AC if the sub intervals are just chosen from $(0,1)$.

Comment: @copper.hat [This definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Definition)

Answer (score 0):

Let $I_n = [a+\frac{1}{n}, b-\frac{1}{n}]$. We have $\cup_n I_n = (a,b)$. If $S \subset (a,b)$, then $f(S) = \cup_n f(S \cap I_n )$.

Suppose $N$ is a null set. Then $N \cap I_n \subset I_n$ is also a null set. Since $f$ is absolutely continuous on any compact sub interval of $(a,b)$, it follows that $f(N \cap I_n)$ is also a null set, and the properties of measure show that $\cup_n f(N \cap I_n )$ is also a null set.

Since $f(N) = \cup_n f(N \cap I_n )$, we have the desired result.